# Servlet multiple request handle at same time on tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I have written a servlet program which is calling a java class to generate the random strings. I have also written an HTML file which has 1000 IFRAME pointing to the servlet address. If multiple requests are going to a servlet then each request will be processed in a separate thread. So in this case, 1000 threads are being created(1000 request). The problem is that it is taking to much of time to processed and not able to handle if requests are more than 1000 and so on. It becomes slower if I do the complex calculation at the back-end. What changes need to be done at the servlet level(multithreading) or at tomcat level(if possible) for the fast response. Any suggestion?

### Servlet Code

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static PrintWriter out=null;
private UserOperation operation=null;
private static int counter=0;
public MyServlet() {
    super();
    operation=new UserOperation();
}
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                            counter++;
                            out=response.getWriter();
                            String output=operation.getResult();
                            System.out.println(counter+":"+output);
                            out.print(output);
                            return;
            }

            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                            doGet(request, response);
            }
}
```

### UserOperation.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class UserOperation {
            private Random rand=null;
            private int max=9;
            private int min=0;
            private static final String [] RESULT= {"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"};
            public UserOperation() {
                            rand=new Random();
            }
            public String getResult() {
                           int randNum=rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
                            return RESULT[randNum];
            }
}
```

### HTML File

1000 times IFRAME call. below line has been copy paste 1000 times in the HTML file.

```
<IFRAME src="http://localhost:8080/MultipleRequest/test" width="30px" height="30px"></IFRAME>
```

Comment: @NathanHughes Using System.out.println is for testing purpose what it will return. That is not a case. Problem is how to handle more request at the same time by the servlet. If you look at my code I am just returning a random string per request and performance wise it's very slow.

Comment: There aren't 1000 threads created... Tomcat by default has 200 request handling threads everything else will be queued until a thread finished processing. Also how realistic is your test.... Next to that it might even be that your browser is blocking concurrent requests and only 6 arrive or even 1 at the time. Also your servlet isn't even thread safe and actually dangerous... Remove the static reference to `PrintWriter` and make it local to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing java.lang.Runnable interface or extending java.lang.Thread class at your UserOperation class for multithreading.
Also try increasing the heapsize of Java by adding -Xmx parameter with appropriate limit.

Comment: Some more examples in your answer would be helpful and keeps the discussion clear.

Comment: Why need to create multiple thread by implementing the Runnable or extending by Thread class. The same part is done by the servlet by creating a thread per request. So each thread is accessing its own UserOperation.

Comment: Well, actually this configuration might need an async servlet configuration which I didn't mention. The multithreading of Servlet itself is not the case here. The inner request in a servlet which is done by a custom class (usually a business logic) should be a Runnable thread and async context is better run this Runnable code. Here is a better explanation for async implementation https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/servlets012.html

Comment: @ashemez I tried your solution and it became even slower. The problem here is how to handle more request at same time by servlet efficiently. I am just doing a small task returning a random string for each request then why it is very slow for this small calculation.

Comment: @Srinath I tested with an async servlet and it resulted all the servlet requests in 15 seconds. I edited my answer, you can find my AsyncServlet code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async servlet with servlet 3.0; there's an example here:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html

There's still an issue of an ongoing connection requiring a port on the server. A request made will take up a port, whether it'll take up a thread or not you can mitigate with event code using the async servlet but the port part will remain regardless. The only way to mitigate a port shortage is to scale your application to multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

First of all your servlet is dangerous and not thread safe. First fix that.

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final UserOperation operation=null;

  public MyServlet() {
    super();
    operation=new UserOperation();
  }
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int count = this.counter.incrementAndGet();
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String output=operation.getResult();
    System.out.println(count + ":" + output);
    out.print(output);
    return;
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
  }
}
```

Now that that is thread safe, the fact that you think that 1000 threads are created is wrong. Tomcat has a default request handling thread pool with a size of 200. So it will handle 200 requests concurrently and not 1000 as you think.

Next to that you shouldn't be using 1000 iframes for testing as your browser is limited to generally 6 concurrent requests to the server. So I actually doubt that you receive 1000 concurrent requests, but only 6 at a time from the browser. Chrome could be even limiting it to 1 at a time as it sees the same URL and tries to cache the results 1 by 1.

So in short I doubt that your servlet is slow but that your test method makes it appear to be slow! Use a proper tool like [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) to send 1000 requests to your server and then test the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing java.lang.Runnable interface or extending java.lang.Thread class at your UserOperation class for multithreading.
Also try increasing the heapsize of Java by adding -Xmx parameter with appropricate limit.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/AsyncServlet"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static PrintWriter out=null;
    private UserOperation operation=null;
    private static int counter=0;

    public AsyncServlet() {
        super();
        operation=new UserOperation();
    }

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response) {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
      acontext.start(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

             counter++;
             try {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) acontext.getResponse();

                out=response.getWriter();

                String param = acontext.getRequest().getParameter("param");

                 String output = operation.getResult();
                 System.out.println(counter + ":"+output);
                 out.print(output);

                acontext.complete();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }

   public class UserOperation {
       private Random rand=null;
       private int max=9;
       private int min=0;
       private final String [] RESULT= {"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"};
       public UserOperation() {
           rand=new Random();
       }
       public String getResult() {
           int randNum=rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
           return RESULT[randNum];
       }
   }
}
```